# How to generate new log files based on size using log4j2 in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am generating a log file using log4j2, but I need to generate a new one based on size each time it reaches the limit.

**log4j2.properties** file:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename =D:\\Users\\User\\MyFiles\\Apache Camel github\\ChatServiceProject\\logs\\propertieslogs.log
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.append=true
appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
appender.fileLogger.MaxFileSize=1KB

loggers=file
logger.file.name=Processors
logger.file.level = trace
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger= INFO, file, stdout
```

However the size of the log file is now 16KB and still it is not generating a new file but appending logs to the same file. So I need help to fix this.
Thank you

Comment: Your appender is a `File` appender, not a `RollingFile` appender, so it performs no rotation.

Answer (score 1):

The below properties can be used to override the default configuration (  **application.propertie**s)

`logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-index=10`

`logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=15MB`

> spring properties can be placed inside the log xml file.

`<springProperty scope="context" name="MAX_INDEX" source="logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-index"/>`

`<springProperty scope="context" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" source="logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size"/>`

> sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/e2e-tools.${nodename:-local}.log}"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="MAX_INDEX" source="logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-index"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" source="logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size" defaultValue="10MB"/>
<appender name="FIX_WINDOW_BASED_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>${MAX_INDEX}</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %level: %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %level: %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FIX_WINDOW_BASED_FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remark**: Spring Boot already defines a log file with rotation (cf. [`log4j2-file.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2-file.xml)) with a size limit of 10 MiB (the limit is hardcoded). You just need to set:

```
logging.file.path=D:\\Users\\User\\MyFiles\\Apache Camel github\\ChatServiceProject\\logs
logging.file.name=propertieslogs.log
```

in your `application.properties`.

If, however, you want to write your own configuration file, you should consider using the XML format:

```xml
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATH">D:\Users\User\MyFiles\Apache Camel github\ChatServiceProject\logs</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_FILE">${sys:LOG_PATH}/propertieslogs.log</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile
            name="LOGFILE"
            append="true"
            fileName="${sys:LOG_FILE}"
            filePattern="${sys:LOG_PATH}/propertieslogs.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
```

The properties format uses a lot of arbitrary identifiers to emulate the hierarchical structure of XML:

```
property.LOG_PATH=D:\Users\User\MyFiles\Apache Camel github\ChatServiceProject\logs
property.LOG_FILE=${sys:LOG_PATH}/propertieslogs.log

appender.<id1>.type=RollingFile
appender.<id1>.name=LOGFILE
appender.<id1>.append=true
appender.<id1>.fileName=${sys:LOG_FILE}
appender.<id1>.filePattern=${sys:LOG_PATH}/propertieslogs.%i.log.gz
appender.<id1>.<id2>.type=PatternLayout
appender.<id1>.<id2>.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.<id1>.<id3>.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.<id1>.<id3>.size=1 KB
```

where `<id1>`, `<id2>` and `<id3>` are strings chosen by you. They have no influence on the configuration.

Comment: hello @Piotr P. Karwasz , you said spring boot by default provides a file rotation, how can  I change the size limit and generate each time a new file with this size using this feature of spring boot?

Comment: As you can see from the [`log4j2-file.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2-file.xml) file I linked in the answer, you can't change the limit: it is hardcoded. However you can copy that file to `log4j2-spring.xml` and modify it.